# ESP32: Is the networking stack running in separate thread? Can you safely block task executed from loop() for longer time? (>3s)

Tags: esp32, nodemcu

With ESP8266 there is a requirement to not block the CPU execution for longer than few ms and then yield to networking stack and internal functions that are executed after each iteration of `loop()`. If you block CPU for too long, network will misbehave. If you block it for longer than ~3 seconds SWDT resets the MCU.

Now with ESP32 you have 2 CPU cores and RTOS running in the background that has full multithreading support. Is the Arduino framework for ESP32 taking advantage of this? Is the whole "user program" running as separate task besides the network and system stack? Would blocking the CPU in main loop cause similar problems as ESP8266?

From `xPortGetCoreID()` we can see that both setup and loop run always from core 1, not core 0, so I assume that user program is by default pinned to core 1 and network stack runs on core 0? Can someone confirm that?

This is just hypothetical question, I am just curious about internal ESP32 architecture and Arduino implementation, not making anything specific.

Comment: In the Arduino IDE you can select on which core the user program shall run, but yes, the default is 1.

Comment: @PMF ok, but does that mean the network stack is running separately in core 0, or is it done in same "everything in 1 thread" way as in ESP8266?

Comment: As far as I know it runs on its own thread (the ESP32 uses a FreeRTOS kernel in the back). I have a project where I run quite expensive operations on the "user" core while a connection is maintained automatically. It should be easy to test this, shouldn't it?